# Failed assertion issue on login page state

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

The following assertion was thrown building LoginPage(dirty, state: _LoginPageState#bf00d):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 360 pos 10: 'data != null'

I have this error and looks like no issue in text.dart.

This is my loginPage.dart page.

I can't find the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sporprojesi/login/primary_button.dart';
import 'package:sporprojesi/login/signin.dart';



class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key key, this.title, this.auth, this.onSignIn}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignIn;

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => new _LoginPageState();
}

enum FormType {
  login,
  register
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  static final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email;
  String _password;
  FormType _formType = FormType.login;
  String _authHint = '';


  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();}

  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        String userId = _formType == FormType.login
            ? await widget.auth.signIn(_email, _password)
            : await widget.auth.createUser(_email, _password);
        setState(() {
          _authHint = 'Signed In\n\nUser id: $userId';
        });
        widget.onSignIn();
      }
      catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          _authHint = 'Sign In Error\n\n${e.toString()}';
        });
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _authHint = '';
      });
    }
  }

  void moveToRegister() {
    formKey.currentState.reset();
    setState(() {
      _formType = FormType.register;
      _authHint = '';
    });
  }

  void moveToLogin() {
    formKey.currentState.reset();
    setState(() {
      _formType = FormType.login;
      _authHint = '';
    });
  }

  List<Widget> usernameAndPassword() {
    return [
      padded(child: new TextFormField(
        key: new Key('email'),
        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
        autocorrect: false,
        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty.' : "",
        onSaved: (val) => _email = val,
      )),
      padded(child: new TextFormField(
        key: new Key('password'),
        decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
        obscureText: true,
        autocorrect: false,
        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'t be empty.' : "",
        onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
      )),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> submitWidgets() {
    switch (_formType) {
      case FormType.login:
        return [
          new PrimaryButton(
              key: new Key('login'),
              text: 'Login',
              height: 44.0,
              onPressed: validateAndSubmit
          ),
          new FlatButton(
              key: new Key('need-account'),
              child: new Text("Need an account? Register"),
              onPressed: moveToRegister
          ),
        ];
      case FormType.register:
        return [
          new PrimaryButton(
              key: new Key('register'),
              text: 'Create an account',
              height: 44.0,
              onPressed: validateAndSubmit
          ),
          new FlatButton(
              key: new Key('need-login'),
              child: new Text("Have an account? Login"),
              onPressed: moveToLogin
          ),
        ];
    }
    return null;
  }

  Widget hintText() {
    return new Container(
      //height: 80.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Text(
            _authHint,
            key: new Key('hint'),
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center)
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(child: new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: new Column(
                children: [
                  new Card(
                      child: new Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                child: new Form(
                                    key: formKey,
                                    child: new Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children: usernameAndPassword() + submitWidgets(),
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                          ])
                  ),
                  hintText()
                ]
            )
        ))
    );
  }

  Widget padded({Widget child}) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like _authHint is null

Modify `hintText` method like below where ?? operator used. Similarly, you should have for other Text Widget if required.

```
 Widget hintText() {
    return new Container(
      //height: 80.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Text(
            _authHint?? "",
            key: new Key('hint'),
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center)
    );
  }
```

Comment: I did but I am still getting same issue

Comment: Can you telll which exact line it is failing

Comment: ı have just this issue              A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 360 pos 10: 'data != null'          and 360. line is this     assert(
         data != null,
         'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
       ),

Comment: Have you added ?? for all Text()

Comment: to be honest ı didnt understand this part  :D Which text should I add?

Comment: Like Text() Widget add ?? with empty String which I added above

Comment: try out adding a print statement for all text which you are using in Text() before they are passed to this widget you will get know which text is giving null value and then config according to that